# Как отключить font-awesome (cdn) в WP

Tags: php, wordpress, css3

Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста не могу на сайте (CMS: Wordpress) отключить загрузку fontawasome по линку: netdna.bootstrapcdn.com

link rel='stylesheet' id='fontawesome_stylesheet-css'  href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css' type='text/css' media='all'

Можете подсказать как это сделать? 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос в статье:
https://wp-kama.ru/question/ne-poluchaetsya-otklyuchit-stili-plagina

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'fontawesome_stylesheet' );
} );
```

Название берется из Html, смотрим ID линка, при этом отнимаем "-сss" и всё!
Возможно кому-то это пригодится!